# Logback default value delimiter not working

Tags: java, logging, aws-lambda, logback, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using `Logback` to configure my logging pattern for a logger that I use in an AWS Lambda Function.

In the pattern I specify which default value to output if the key is nog present in my thread context.

This works in all cases except for the traceId.

This is my pattern:

```
<encoder>
    <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", UTC} awsRequestId:%X{AWSRequestId:-n/a} parentTraceId:%X{parentTraceId:-n/a} traceId:%X{traceId:-n/a} %.-6level %logger{5} - %msg &#xd;%replace(%ex){'\n','&#xd;'}%nopex%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

Below you find an example output for when the AWSRequestId is present in the context, the parentTraceId and traceId are not present.

```
2019-07-24T12:33:52.857Z awsRequestId:ff2ddb5d-d1a8-4ebe-b840-8b484b14efc3 parentTraceId:n/a traceId: INFO c.n.s.s.l.MyLambda
```

As you can see the AWSRequestId is correctly logged. For the parentTraceId the default 'n/a' value is correctly used. But for the traceId the default is not used.

***How come the default value is not used for traceId?***

Comment: Is it possible that `parentTraceId` is `null` and `traceId` is just an empty string?